# How to input user_id in different table (laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have 2 tables.

1. `users` (`id`, `name`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `admin`, `remember_token`)
2. `dosen` (`iddosen`, `user_id`, `namadosen`, `birthdate`, `address`)

How to insert `user_id` and `namadosen` same as in table `users`?

My method :

```
public function store(CreateDosenRequest $request)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $request->input('name'),
        'username' => $request->input('username'),
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
        'password' => bcrypt($request->input['password']),
        'admin' => $request->input('admin')
 ]);

      $dosen = Dosen::create([
        'iddosen' => $request->input('iddosen'),
        'name' => $request->input('namadosen'),
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'address' => $request->input('address'),
        'birthdate' => $request->input('birthdate'),

]);


    return redirect('admin')->with('message', 'Success!');              
}
```

following code doesn't work

```
 'user_id' => $user->id,
```

Comment: Have you checked the user creating, is the inserting successful?

The `create` method just work with mass assignable attributes - [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent).

Comment: @haitran it's working. but user_id and namadosen in table Dosen is null.

Comment: Is user_id a fillable field in Dosen model?

Comment: @Ezra As I have said, the create method just work with mass assignable attributes (i.e. fillable filed as @jedrzej.kurylo points out). You should check that. If the user is successful created, then the `$user->id` will work!

Comment: ah my mistake, i forgot to make user_id as fillable filed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just answering this for consistency sake.

As stated in the comments, the issue was that `user_id` wasn't specified as a `$fillable` field inside the `Dosen` model.

Adding `user_id` to the `$fillable` array solved the issue for OP.